# How to do VLOOKUP based on multiple criteria and return the latest rows result?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently when I use Vlookup, it provides for first matching occurrence of data.

I receive data into a spreadsheet by date, i.e., a record existing for every project with values for status field. I build a consolidated report in a new tab at project level, I need to populate the 'STATUS' column for each project.

The status field value could remain same for few days but would change on a certain date. If I use VLOOKP(Project#, SampleData! Project#:Status, 7 , 0) I would get for first match i.e., most likely will get always 'In-Progress' as result

How can I add another criteria in VLOOKUP to search for max of dates upon the matching project# & return the result?

Google Sheet [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17SERwlkkcPWeFcOfJnDJAbNtD2BIUCryTjV03_GfoGg/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Sample Raw Data]

[image: Consolidated View]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 added copy of sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If projects are sorted by date in ascending order, you can use `LOOKUP` function to get last status:

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/(A11=$B$2:$B$7),$H$2:$H$7))
```

if not sorted, then try following:

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/((A11=$B$2:$B$7)*(MAX($A$2:$A$7*(A11=$B$2:$B$7))=$A$2:$A$7)),$H$2:$H$7))
```

[image]

**Explanation:**

Here is used `LOOKUP` feature if search key is not found, the lookup will return the last closest matching key in the range with a lower value. In first formula `LOOKUP` search for value `2` while expression `1/(A11=$B$2:$B$7)` returns array with errors and ones `{1/TRUE,1/TRUE,1/TRUE,1/FALSE,1/FALSE,1/FALSE} => {1,1,1,DIV/0,DIV/0,DIV/0}` so `LOOKUP` returns value from third row in range $H$2:$H$7.

In the second formula, by analogy.

Comment: yes this perfectly works. Would you mind explaining the formula?

Comment: actually @basic shouldn't the value in status be 'In-progressM' because for 1234 has latest date as Oct 13 2020 whose Status = 'In-progressM' and 1233, dated Oct 16 2020 whose status = 'In-progressM'???

Comment: @shafeeqrahaman yeah, my mistake - I had attached an image with unsorted data and a formula for sorted data. Corrected.

Comment: @basic watch out, the external `IF` function is populating the column with the top cell's same result. You should remove it and drag the formula down instead.

Comment: @Alessandro yes, you're right, thanks, I had missed it. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

### Using VLOOKUP

Leveraging the `ARRAYFORMULA` function you can build a search_key for your range:

This will basically multiply the `Boolean` result of the `EQ` function (`=`) for all the possible dates and then take the maximum.

Note: Boolean values are also represented as `1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE`, so every date that is not for the corresponding Project code will result in a very old timestamp.

I will then use this as a search_key to get the status (col 8) for the Project code subset range (built with the `IF` function):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
     VLOOKUP(
         MAX($A$2:$A$7*(A11=$B$2:$B$7)), 
         IF(A11=$B$2:$B$7, $A$2:$H$7),
         8,
         FALSE
     )
)
```

Dragging down this formula for each project code will return its last status.

### Using QUERY

If you prefer to use the `QUERY` formula instead of the `VLOOKUP` here is an example:

The query is based on a sub-query that basically leverages the `max()` aggregate function to find the max date for a specific Project code.

Then it uses this maximum date and the Project code as a key to be sure to exclude date duplicates that belong to other Project codes.

```
=QUERY(
    $A$1:$H$7, 
    "select H where A = date '"& TEXT(
        Query(
             $A$2:$H$7,
             "select max(A) where B = "&A11&" label max(A) ''",
             1
        ),
    "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'",
     0
)
```

Here as well dragging down the formula will return the Project last status.

### References

[VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en&ref_topic=9054531)

[IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en&ref_topic=9054531)

Comment: thank you this also helps, really great explanation you have provided.